# Figure number of unnumbered chapter

Tags: captions, page

I'm writting a PhD thesis with a template of my university (documentclass "book"). I have some chapters unnumbered (Introduction, Context...), and on this unnumbered chapters I have figures. 
The caption of numbered chapters is like:

"Fig. I.1: [...]"  "Fig. II.1: [...]" etc

But in the unnumbered chapters the caption is:

"Fig. .1: [...]"

That's my problem. I can not find any macro that let the numbered chapters the way they are, and change the unnumbered chapters...

Thanks for your help.

Gemma

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,diffusion]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Configuration fichier
\include{0-configuration/configuration}

% Include user's macros
\include{0-configuration/macros}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% CUSTOM PACKAGES %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%fabrication automatique des pages première et quatrième  couverture
\usepackage{1-openingAndClosing/thcover}
\usepackage{1-openingAndClosing/versionswitch}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%% les pages liminaires %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\frontcover
\frontmatter

% Include the acknowledgements page
%\include{1-openingAndClosing/remerciements}

% Build the general table of contents
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\tableofcontents

% Build the list of figures
\listoffigures

% Build the list of tables
\listoftables

% Nomenclature
\input{1-openingAndClosing/acronyms.tex}
\printnomenclature

%%%%%%%%% le corps du texte %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%Introduction 
\include{2-chapters/0/MainChapter}
\phantomsection
\clearpage
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}

\mainmatter
%Chapter 1
\include{2-chapters/1/MainChapter}

%Chapter 2
\include{2-chapters/2/MainChapter}

% Chapter 3
\include{2-chapters/3/MainChapter}

% Chapter 4
\include{2-chapters/4/MainChapter}

% Chapter 5
\include{2-chapters/5/MainChapter}

% Chapter 6
\include{2-chapters/6/MainChapter}

\clearpage
\appendix 
%Appendix 1
\include{3-appendices/1/MainAppendix}

%Appendix 2
\include{3-appendices/2/MainAppendix}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%% les pages finales %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\backmatter
\nocite{*} %%% pour les test mais à proscire !!

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Bbliographie %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%% utilisation de BiBTeX
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliographie}

\bibliographystyle{thesefr-href}   % ne pas mettre l'extension .bst

\bibliography{4-bibliography/references_2}

%\usepackage{biblatex}
%\addbibresource{4-bibliography/references}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\backcover
\end{document}
```

Comment: In unnumberd chapter, what form of figure number do you want to have?

Comment: For unnumbered chapter's images, you can use as `\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}`...

Comment: Muzimuzhi, Arabic numbers i think...

Comment: MadyYuvi Thanks! It works! 
But so, if I have 3 unnumbered chapters with 1 figure each one, i will have 3 figures 1?